# Modificar el activity_main_drawer.xml desde un xml de un servidor externo

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo este archivo `activity_main_drawer.xml` dentro de la carpeta `res/menu/`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_inicio"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_home"
            android:title="@string/inicio" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Lo que intento hacer es modificarlo, en función de un `xml` que obtengo de un servidor externo.O en vez de modificarlo, usar el `xml` externo, en lugar de este para el menú lateral de `android`

**EDIT**

El xml del servidor es como este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zonas>
    <zona>
        <idZona>1</idZona>
        <nombre idZona="1">Home</nombre>
    </zona>
    <zona>
        <idZona>2</idZona>
        <nombre idZona="2">Pantalla 1</nombre>
    </zona>
    <zona>
        <idZona>3</idZona>
        <nombre idZona="3">Pantalla 2</nombre>
    </zona>
    <zona>
        <idZona>4</idZona>
        <nombre idZona="4">Pantalla 3</nombre>
    </zona>
</zonas>
```

Y lo leo mediante `Parser SAX`

Comment: Podrias añadir el xml externo y como lo optienes

Comment: @AndoniAlda ya lo he añadido

Comment: Donde usas ese menu? Me parece que más que modificar el xml, podés modificar donde ese xml se usa.

Comment: Es el menu lateral de la app @Juan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sino me equivoco puedes cambiar los elementos del Navigation Drawer en el método `OnCreate()` de tu `Activity`. En un principio se me ocurren varias opciones:

-**Opción 1**: cambiar el menú por otro que exista en los recursos.
Ejemplo:

```
 navigationView.getMenu().clear(); //Borrar los elementos anteriores.
 navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.new_navigation_drawer_items);
```

-**Opción 2**: cambiar el menú añadiendo a mano los elementos del menú utilizando las funciones propias del menú [add() y addSubMenu()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add%28int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) . Ejemplo:

```
 Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
 for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
     menu.add("Menu "+ i);
 }

 SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu("SubMenu");
 for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
     subMenu.add("SubMenu " + i);
 }
```